# How I can correctly import this remote server certifcate (.crt file) in order to perform an HTTPS request from WSO2 ESB application?

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-esb

I am absolutly new in **WSO2 ESB** and I am going crazy trying to correctly implement an **HTTPS POST** call from an implemented API. It seems that I have some problem related to the **SSL certificate** that I can't resolve.

So basically I have the following situation:

from my bash shell I can perform a **CURL** call toward a remote webservice exposed on **HTTPS** passing to its certificate into the related **.crt** file (I have obtained this certificate file exporting it from Firefox):

```
$ curl --cacert 52708968.crt https://XX.YY.ZZ.WW/myProject/xml/manager
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   129  100   129    0     0    201      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   201<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response><error>XML document does not appear to begin with "&lt;?xml"</error></response>
```

As you ca see it works because I am obtaining the expected response without any problem.

Ok, so in my **WSO2 ESB** project I have created the endpoint pointing to this URL: **https://XX.YY.ZZ.WW/myProject/xml/manager**.

Then I defined my API in this way (saved into **RegisterReourceAPI.xml** file of my project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/registerResource" name="RegisterResourceAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/registerResource/">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Request Log" level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="&quot;Welcome to Resource Registration Service&quot;"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="QueryWsEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

So to starts the execution flow I have to perform this request into my shell:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8280/registerResource/registerResource/
```

But doing so I obtain the following error:

1) Into the shell where I perform the CURL call I obtain this timeout:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8280/registerResource/registerResource/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8280 (#0)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0> GET /registerResource/registerResource/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8280
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.0
> Accept: */*
>
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:00 --:--:--     0* Empty reply from server
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:00 --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

2) Into the **WSO2 ESB** console I obtain this exception:

```
[2017-03-13 12:24:31,276]  INFO - LogMediator message = "Welcome to Resource Registration Service"
[2017-03-13 12:24:31,284]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2017-03-13 12:24:31,564] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.handshakeAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2017-03-13 12:24:31,603]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : QueryWsEP with address https://XX.YY.ZZ.WW/MYPROJECT/xml/manager will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2017-03-13 12:24:31,604]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : QueryWsEP with address https://XX.YY.ZZ.WW/MYPROJECT/xml/manager - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Mon Mar 13 12:25:01 CET 2017
[2017-03-13 12:27:31,317]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-1 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:52188
```

So I have found this tutorial: http://yasassriratnayake.blogspot.it/2016/04/how-to-get-rid-of-handshake-alert.html

that simply says to add **-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false** to the **JVM property**. So I have add it into the server VM-arguments into Eclipse server settings:

[image]

Performing again the CURL call to execute the ESB application flow now I obtain these different exceptions:

```
[2017-03-14 13:05:58,883]  INFO - LogMediator message = "Welcome to Resource Registration Service"
[2017-03-14 13:05:58,891]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2017-03-14 13:06:03,788] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doWrap(SSLIOSession.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:255)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:293)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
[2017-03-14 13:06:03,815]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : QueryWsEP with address https://XX.YY.ZZ.WW/MYPROJECT/xml/manager will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2017-03-14 13:06:03,816]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : QueryWsEP with address https://XX.YY.ZZ.WW/MYPROJECT/xml/manager - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Tue Mar 14 13:06:33 CET 2017
```

It seems that is something related certificate...as it can't find the certificate...so I think: "ok in the first CURL request you have manually added this certificate (the **52708968.crt** file), I have to add this certificate also into WSO2 ESB server".

So I acces to the **WSO2 ESB** administraton panel (https://192.168.249.1:9443/carbon/) and:

1) **Keystore --> List** and here I can found the **wso2carbon.jks** file:

[image]

2) Then I clicked on the **Import Cert** button to add my **52708968.crt** to this keystore and I have done:

[image]

3) So this cert seems to be correctly added to my keystore, infact now I can see in the cert list:

[image]

So the certificate to connect to the external web service via **HTTPS** should be imported.

4) I restarted the server and I perform again the request that starts the **WSO2 ESB application** execution flows:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8280/registerResource/registerResource/
```

but I still obtain exactly the previous exceptions !!!

How is it possible? The certificate is setted inside the keystore. What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the certificate inside:

```
[WSO2_HOME]/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
[WSO2_HOME]/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
```

Using:

```
keytool -importcert -file $path/your_certificate.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks -alias "youralias"

keytool -importcert -file $path/your_certificate.cer -keystore wso2carbon.jks -alias "youralias"
```

Comment: What exactly have I to do? I have to perform these 2 statments into my console?  Doubts: 1) What is the "your_certificate.cer" you mentioned? is it my 52708968.crt file or something else? 2) What have I to use instead "youralias"? 3) What exactly does these 2 statmens? Tnx

Comment: with both statements you import your remote certificate inside your keystores...alias can be any name, and your_certificate.cer it´s your certificate in cer format, try with .crt any way...and yes, you perform in a windows or linux console...keytool came with the jdk/jre

Comment: mmm I try to perform keytool -importcert -file 52708968.crt -keystore client-truststore.jks -alias "registerWS" but it is asking me tge "keystore password". I am missing something but what is this password? Is it creating a new keystore (so maybe have I to insert a new password) or an existing keystore?

Comment: default pass = wso2carbon